# Align class within td element

Tags: html, css, datatables

I'm trying to align a p class within a td element on my forum plugin I'm writing for my CMS. I use Datatables to draw the forum and have just been styling the datatables accordingly. I now want to align the p class to the bottom of the table data, but unfortunately it does not work. I don't want to move the rest of the data in the table data as a side note.

```
.votes {
vertical-align:bottom;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

[image: View of what I'm working on]

```
<td class="content">'.htmlspecialchars_decode($row['content']).'</td><td class="details perimter">Posted On '.$row['postdate'].'
            <p class = "votes"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Downvote"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a> <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Upvote"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a></p></td></tr>
```

Comment: Where is .votes class used? Please post some HTML/CSS codes.

Comment: Added just for you @GauravRai

Comment: Downvote with no reasoning as to why. The question is clear. the issue is presented. It's not as simple as a google search as that comes up with no relevant help. Awesome.

Comment: Please show how your markup looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Add the following CSS rules to position votes section at the left bottom of the cell:

```css
td.details {
   position:relative;
}

td.details .details-container {
   margin-bottom:1.4em;
}

td.details .votes {
   position:absolute;
   left:10px;
   bottom:10px;
   margin:0;
}
```

Wrap content of Details cell in `<div class="details-container"></div>` as follows:

```html
<td class="details perimter">
   <div class="details-container">

   <!-- ... skipped ... -->

   </div>
</td>
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qtgj7nv/3/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm, thank you so much! Datatables is just too good for me to pass up for a forum, takes care of quite a bit automatically.